# Are Greek Myths and Heroes Rooted in actual History and People?

Tags: greek, comparative, theseus, perseus

I completed reading a book titled "Old Greek Stories" by James Baldwin.

It features some well known Ancient Heroes such as Theseus & Perseus.

But the way it was told seemed like several nations and locations in that world (Crete/Aegean/Thebes) got their name or origin as a result of some hero's journey.
Such as the Formation of Athens.

Are Greek Hero stories rooted in real Life persons ? 
Were they part of the narrative constructed to glorify a Ruler, or by Inhabitants of a Society to show them of superior pedigree ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to M&F SE, please take some time to take our [tour](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tour/). Looking at your question, it is indeed interesting but I think it is a bit too wide since you are basically asking about the whole mythology origins. I think you should better focus on an event or a unique character (as many of those events/characters might have many different origins).

Comment: I wanted to flag this question as overly-broad, but if someone is willing to create a community answer to be improved over-time, this could be a good addition to the site instead of hundreds of character/event focused questions.

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask you if your question is focused on Perseus and Theseus since you tagged them to then widen the question to all the heroes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wikipedia article for [Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theseus) ends its introduction with this:

> As the subject of myth, the existence of Theseus as a real person has
>   not been proven, but scholars believe that he may have been alive
>   during the Late Bronze Age possibly as a king in the 8th or 9th
>   century BC.

This assertion is based on [Classical Mythology Tenth Edition](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780199997329/student/materials/chapter23/commentary/). Quoting the relevant parts:

> **History and Legend.** Theseus of all the legendary heroes has the strongest claims to being a real person. As stated above, he was for
>   Plutarch a historical figure and he very likely was one of the kings
>   of Athens perhaps in the ninth or eighth century B.C. But serious
>   historical and chronological problems arise when we try to understand
>   how he appears as the great conqueror of the legendary Minotaur and a
>   king of Athens in the earlier Mycenaean Age and also a later king of
>   Athens who has more serious claims to reality. Were there two
>   Theseuses or only one, around whom all the stories clustered? Some
>   scholars question the traditional dates established for the Dark Age
>   that descended upon Greece after the fall of the Mycenaean kingdoms,
>   ca. 1100–800 B.C.; on the basis of comparative studies, they would
>   eliminate this Dark Age altogether or at least place the chronology of
>   the legendary Mycenaean kings of Athens much closer in time to the
>   chronology of the later historical monarchy, thus making one
>   historical Theseus more comprehensible.
>
> The excavations of Sir Arthur Evans in Crete seem to confirm details
>   of Minoan-Mycenaean and Athenian saga. For one thing, the elaborate
>   palace at Cnossus with its complexity of levels and maze of rooms does
>   suggest a labyrinth. For the history and archaeology of the Minoan and
>   Mycenaean period, see MLS, Chapter 2.

<sup>Morford, Mark; Lenardon, Robert J.; Sham, Michael. "[Classical Mythology Tenth Edition](https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/9780199997329/student/materials/chapter23/commentary/)". Oxford University Press. Oxford University Press.</sup>

Worth mentioning too the idea of [Euhemerism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euhemerism):

> an approach to the interpretation of mythology in which mythological
>   accounts are presumed to have originated from real historical events
>   or personages. Euhemerism supposes that historical accounts become
>   myths as they are exaggerated in the retelling, accumulating
>   elaborations and alterations that reflect cultural mores. It was named
>   for the Greek mythographer
>   [Euhemerus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euhemerus), who lived in the
>   late 4th century BC. In the more recent literature of myth, such as
>   Bulfinch's Mythology, euhemerism is termed the "historical theory" of
>   mythology.

Answer (score -1):

You know , even the biggest lies have a faded sign of truth inside. Just like many other myths , I am pretty sure that these myths are an exaggerated ways of saying the truth.

Comment: Hi and welcome to M&F SE, please take some time to take our [tour](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, your answer seems more like a feeling than an actual answer. As @Rodia answered, we expect answer to be quoting some work or texts to support the claims pointed. We expect as well a detailed reasoning. I don't want to scare you away from this SE but please keep those points in mind next time you want to participate here!